# React JS - can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, axios

I have my Application in React JS. I am fetching data from an API at http://localhost:8080/api/list:

Here is the data that I am getting from the REST API in the Google Chrome console:

```
0:{
    id: 4
    supplierFirstname: "Tom"
    supplierLastName: "ABC"
    supplierTitle: "TomTheSupplier"
    accountNumber: 1122234444
    address: "111 ADrive, 1234 ST."
    companyName: "TheTom Company & Associates"
    email: "tomtomjayjay@email.com"
    hourlyRate: 29
    phoneNumber: 123456789
    otherPhoneNumber: 1023456789
    paymentTerms: "Credit"
    notes: "Some Supplier"
    createdAt: null
    typeOfGoods: "Supplies"
    website: "www.abc_123.com"
    products: [{…}]
    components: 
        [
            0: {id: 5, name: "AComponent", unit: null, quantity: 0, componentCost: 0, …}
        ]
    
}
```

Here is my React code:

```
class SupplierData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      supplier: [
        {
          id: 0,
          supplierTitle: "Supplier Title",
          supplierFirstName: "First Name",
          supplierLastName: "Last Name",
          companyName: "Company Name",
          phoneNumber: "Phone Number",
          otherPhoneNumber: "Phone Number (Other)",
          accountNumber: "Account Number",
          email: "Email",
          address: "Address",
          website: "Website",
          hourlyRate: "Hourly Rate",
          typeOfGoods: "Type Of Goods",
          paymentTerms: "Payment Terms",
          createdAt: "Created At",
          notes: "Notes",
          products: "Products",
          components: "Components",
        },
      ],
      errorMessage: [],
    };
    this.ListAllSuppliers = this.ListAllSuppliers.bind(this);
  }

  ListAllSuppliers = async () => {
    return await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`)
      .then((response) => {
        let apiResults = response.data;
        console.log(apiResults);
        this.setState({ supplier: apiResults });    <--- The error happens here.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: this.state.errorMessage.push(error) });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ListAllSuppliers();
  }
}

export default SupplierData;
```

The problem that I am facing is in the React State. I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might 
         indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = 
         {};` class property with the desired state in the SupplierData component.
```

**Question:**
I want to set the state.

What is a possible fix the above error?

Comment: Looks good at first glance....

Comment: Remove this line from your constructor. 
`this.ListAllSuppliers = this.ListAllSuppliers.bind(this);`. You don't need this because `ListAllSuppliers` is an arrow function

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! It happens that you've added non-relevant tags to this question. The tags `node.js` and `rxjs` are not relevant to the topics of the question. Please consider that a tag may not be relevant to your specific question, even if it's relevant to your project at large.

Answer (score 2):

The code itself is mostly fine, though you're mixing calls to `.then` and `.catch` with `async`/`await` which is not best practice, and you're using `bind` unnecessarily on an arrow function.

It sounds like your component is getting unmounted after you've started your `axios` call and before it returns, which results in your calling `setState` on a component that isn't mounted. (Although the wording of the error is slightly different from the one I've seen.)

To avoid that, you can [cancel](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) the axios call from `componentWillUnmount` by passing a `cancelToken` in the options, and using the `cancel` method on its `source` from `componentWillUnmount`. (The built-in [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) offers the same functionality via [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController).) (If you were doing something that didn't support cancellation, as a fallback, you could set `this.unmounted` in `componentWillUnmount` and then check that and not call `setState` if you see that `this.unmounted` is true.)

There are a few other issues with the code; here's an updated version with the cancel token mentioned above and other issues addressed inline (see comments):

```
class SupplierData extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            supplier: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    supplierTitle: "Supplier Title",
                    supplierFirstName: "First Name",
                    supplierLastName: "Last Name",
                    companyName: "Company Name",
                    phoneNumber: "Phone Number",
                    otherPhoneNumber: "Phone Number (Other)",
                    accountNumber: "Account Number",
                    email: "Email",
                    address: "Address",
                    website: "Website",
                    hourlyRate: "Hourly Rate",
                    typeOfGoods: "Type Of Goods",
                    paymentTerms: "Payment Terms",
                    createdAt: "Created At",
                    notes: "Notes",
                    products: "Products",
                    components: "Components"
                },
            ],
            errorMessage: [],
        };
        // No need to bind `listAllSuppliers`, you don't use it as a callback

        // A single cancel source that can cancel multiple operations
        this.cancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    }

    // Use an async method
    // Note the initial lower case `l` (not `L`), which is standard in JavaScript
    async listAllSuppliers() {
        // In an `async` function, you use `try`/`catch` and `await`, not
        // `.then` / `.catch` methods
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                `http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`,
                {cancelToken: this.cancelSource.token}
            );
            const supplier = response.data;
            console.log(supplier)
            this.setState({supplier});
        } catch (error) {
            // Updating state based on existing state requires the callback form
            // of `setState` , and you must never directly modify state objects
            this.setState(({errorMessage}) => ({
                errorMessage: [...errorMessage, error]
            }));
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.listAllSuppliers();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // Cancel any outstanding axios calls
        this.cancelSource.cancel("Component unmounted");
    }

    // Presumably you do have a `render` method, you'd get a different React error if you didn't
    render() {
        // ...
    }
}

export default SupplierData;
```

Comment: @Thomas - Thank you! I searched for "signal" because of [the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). (I also searched for "abort" and **thought** I searched for [my preferred term] "cancel," but clearly not!)

Comment: @abc_123 - The call above is really straightforward. If you're not seeing it at the backend, that's a backend issue unrelated to this question. I hope you figure it out!